# In flex 4.5 parentDocument did not working as in flex 4.0. How to call parentDocument in flex 4.5?

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, adobe, flex4, flex4.5

In flex 4.0 this code works:

```
<s:WindowedApplication xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
                   xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
                   xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" width="500" height="600">
<fx:Script>
    <![CDATA[
        import componentCanvas;

        import mx.containers.TitleWindow;
        import mx.controls.Alert;

        public function createChild():void{
            var c:componentCanvas = new componentCanvas;
            c.x = 20;
            c.y=20;
            toInclude.addChild(c);
        }
    ]]> 
</fx:Script>
<mx:Button click="createChild()"/>
<mx:Canvas id="toInclude"/>
```

--componentCanvas --

```
<mx:Canvas xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
       xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
       xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" width="400" height="300">
<fx:Script>
    <![CDATA[
        import componentCanvas;
        import mx.containers.TitleWindow;
        import mx.controls.Alert;
        import mx.managers.PopUpManager;
        import popAll;

        public function oh():void{
            Alert.show("From titleWindow");
        }

        public function open():void{
            var pop:popAll = popAll(PopUpManager.createPopUp(this, popAll, true));

        }
    ]]>
</fx:Script>
<mx:Label text="Canvas" x="100" y="100"/>
<mx:Button click="open()"/>
```

-- popAll --

```
<s:TitleWindow xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
           xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
           xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" width="400" height="300" x="40" y="40" close="closePopUp()">
<fx:Script>
    <![CDATA[
        import mx.managers.PopUpManager;
        public function closePopUp():void{
            super.parentDocument.oh();
            PopUpManager.removePopUp(this);
        }
    ]]>
</fx:Script>
<mx:Button click="closePopUp()"/>
```

When I call parentDocument in titleWindow in flex 4 all is fine.
The same code in 4.5 did not work.

Is there a way to do this in Flex 4.5?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calling `parentDocument` and using `public` functions across all the files is definitely not the best practice! Instead, you should really look into the [Event Life Cycle](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/Flex/4.0/UsingSDK/WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf64a29-7fff.html) in Flex and how to use it. In my opinion, public methods should really be created when you want to expose a particular functionality of your component to it's users.

Basically, you should dispatch an event from the `popAll` class and listen to it within it's instance created in `componentCanvas`. So, to solve this issue, your code should be :

popAll:

```
<s:TitleWindow xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
               xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
               xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" width="400" height="300" x="40" y="40" close="closePopUp()">
    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            import mx.managers.PopUpManager;

            public function closePopUp():void{
                this.dispatchEvent(new Event("closePopup"));
                PopUpManager.removePopUp(this);
            }
        ]]>
    </fx:Script>
    <mx:Button click="closePopUp()"/>
</s:TitleWindow>
```

and componentCanvas:

```
<mx:Canvas xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
           xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
           xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" width="400" height="300">
    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            import mx.controls.Alert;
            import mx.managers.PopUpManager;

            private var pop:popAll;

            public function oh():void{
                Alert.show("From titleWindow");
            }

            public function open():void{
                pop = popAll(PopUpManager.createPopUp(this, popAll, true));
                pop.addEventListener("closePopup", onClosePopupRequested);

            }

            protected function onClosePopupRequested(event:Event):void
            {
                pop.removeEventListener("closePopup", onClosePopupRequested); 
                oh();
            }

        ]]>
    </fx:Script>
    <mx:Label text="Canvas" x="100" y="100"/>
    <mx:Button click="open()"/>
</mx:Canvas>
```

As per the code above, I am dispatching a new Event called as `closePopup` from the popAll class and listening to it where I am creating it's instance. And then once the event is caught, I am removing the event handler and then calling your `oh()` method from within the event handler.

I would make a few more recommendations on your code:

- Re-consider your naming convention of classes and methods, and please look into camel case naming convention
- Avoid using too many public methods, instead use events to communicate between files/components. This would enable you to create loosely coupled components.
- If you are moving to Flex 4.5, I would recommend you to use `spark` components instead of `mx` components. In my experience, they do have more versatility.
- Look into creating constants for literals.

Hope this helps. Cheers.

Comment: Exactly! Events is the answer!  Hierarchy is not suitable. Thanks!

Comment: @VGG Please mark as selected answer so that it is helpful for other users. Glad to help. Thanks.